# How can I obtain $x$ and $y$ rotation of an object in its reference frame when it is rotated/measured from another frame of reference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, gyroscopes

I am working with the gyroscope on a mobile device. The goal is to get the x and y rotation of my phone from its reference frame no matter the direction I am pointed in real-life along the z-axis in some space. The only values I can retrieve are the gyroscopes attitude along the `X,Y,Z` in some space.

As an example, imagine you are holding your phone in the palm of your right hand in portrait mode. If you rotate your phone to the left or the right you are rotating it along the `Y-axis`. If you tilt your phone forwards and backwards, you are rotating it along the `X-axis`. If you spin your entire body `45 degrees` keeping your phone in the same place in the palm of your hand, how do you retrieve the same values for rotation by spinning your phone left and right? (I hope this makes sense..)

This seems like a simple problem to have, but I can't resolve it for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. An example image is below:

[image: Example]

Comment: Check out **homogeneous transformations**. They are used in robotics.

Comment: you have to solve this differential equations 

$\dot{\varphi}+\sin(\vartheta)\,\dot{\psi}=0$ and $\dot{\vartheta}-\sin(\varphi)\,\dot{\psi}=0$ . you know the angular velocity about the z axes $\dot{\psi}$ the solution give you the rotation angle about the x-axes $\varphi(t)$ and about the y-axes $\vartheta(t)$